# Get() in R returns "Object xyz not found" for data frame field

Tags: r, get

The base function get() in R is not allowing me to reference a column in a data frame:

```
x <- data.frame(y=c(1,2,3), z=c(4,5,6))
get("x$y")
> Error in get("x$y") : object 'x$y' not found
get("x[,1]")
>Error in get("x[,1]") : object 'x[,1]' not found
x$y
>[1] 1 2 3
```

So the data exists, but base::get is somehow not recognizing it as an object. How do I use get() to reference a single column within a data frame?

Comment: You are using `get` incorrectly; `get("x")$y` would work.

Comment: `with(mtcars,get("mpg"))` also works.

Comment: The point is that `x$y` is not an object in the environment (but `x` is)

Comment: "y" is an object that exists in "x" -- i.e. `get("y", x)`

Comment: @alexis_laz That's a much more sensible version of what I suggested. Silly me.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: @joran : To be honest, I got it to work by accident after failing to make `get("y", envir = x)` work (as e.g. `evalq(y, envir = x)`). "pos" argument seems more flexible than sensible...

Answer (score 0):

[`get`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/get) looks up names of variables; it won't parse and evaluate arbitrary code.  For that, you need [`eval`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/eval) and [`parse`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/parse).  For example

```
eval(parse(text = "x$y"))
```

Note that using eval + parse is considered bad for under most circumstances.  This is because it makes it easier to create and harder to find bugs.